# The Perfect Square with BIT WISE AND

Tags: c++, bitwise-and, contiguous

How to optimize the solution of counting number of perfect square of the of the contiguous sub arrays when bit wise AND operation is performed on the sub arrays.
The Time Complexity should be O(n) or O(n*logn).

Here is the naive approach

```html
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int l=2,r=5;
int c=0;  // for counting the subsets 
for(int i=l;i<=r;i++){
    int val=a[i];
    for(int j=i;j<=r;j++){
        val=val&a[j];
        if(isPerfectSquare(val)){
            c+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding a tag of language you are wanting to use. Though the code looks like C++. Also, mention what you have tried already.

Comment: Thank you, actually this was the partial code written in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ND of numbers can change no more than LogN time, and hence there are at most O(NLogN) different values possible. It is hence possible to update answer over a group or range, which can be done via segment tree or fenwick tree.**

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;
int n, m, t, l, r, a[100005];
ll d[2][100005], ans[500005];
vector< pair<int, int> > rs[100005];
//vector for groups with equal AND
vector< pair<int, int> > groups;
//fenwick tree
ll sum(ll num, ll pos)
{
    ll sm = 0;
    while(pos >= 0)
    {
        sm += d[num][pos];
        pos = (pos & (pos + 1)) - 1;
    }
    return sm;
}
void update(ll num, ll pos, ll x)
{
    while(pos < n)
    {
        d[num][pos] += x;
        pos = (pos | (pos + 1));
    }
}
int main()
{
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        scanf("%d", &m);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
            d[0][i] = d[1][i] = 0;
            rs[i].clear();
        }
        d[0][n] = d[1][n] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d%d", &l, &r);
            l--;
            r--;
            rs[r].push_back({l, i});
        }
        groups.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            //new vector for groups
            vector< pair<int, int> > newgroups;
            for(int j = 0; j < groups.size(); j++)
            {
                int cur = groups[j].first & a[i];
                if(!j || cur != newgroups[newgroups.size() - 1].first)
                {
                    newgroups.push_back({cur, groups[j].second});
                }
            }
            if(newgroups.size() == 0 || newgroups[newgroups.size() - 1].first != a[i])
                newgroups.push_back({a[i], i});
            //making new vector current
            groups = newgroups;
            for(int j = 0; j < groups.size(); j++)
            {
                //checking for a perfect square
                int sq = floor(sqrt(groups[j].first));
                if((sq - 1) * (sq - 1) == groups[j].first || sq * sq == groups[j].first || (sq + 1) * (sq + 1) == groups[j].first)
                {
                    //getting a borders
                    l = groups[j].second;
                    if(j != groups.size() - 1)
                        r = groups[j + 1].second - 1;
                    else
                        r = i;
                    //adding an arithmetic progression
                    update(0, l, (r + 1));
                    update(0, r + 1, -(r + 1));
                    update(1, l, 1);
                    update(1, r + 1, -1);
                    //adding on a prefix
                    update(0, 0, r - l + 1);
                    update(0, l, -(r - l + 1));
                }
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < rs[i].size(); j++)
            {
                //getting an answer for a query
                ans[rs[i][j].second] = sum(0, rs[i][j].first);
                ans[rs[i][j].second] -= sum(1, rs[i][j].first) * rs[i][j].first;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            printf("%lld\n", ans[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Time  Complexity=O(QLogN+N∗LogA∗LogN) (setter's solution) 
Space Complexity=O(NLogAi) where Ai is maximum element in A approximately.

Answer (score 2):

You may make a Trie Data Structure of bits of the number and keep inserting the pre_and. Also, remember to make the Node structure store the index of the number so that you may make a query run for the given range. What's left now is to just calculate if the AND result is a perfect square. Try it for yourself. The hint is enough. You may refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-subarray-xor-in-a-given-array/)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me

Comment: Post a solution as well for everyone to see. Always remember to share if you get the correct answer.